# Nexus 4 won't turn Bluetooth on

Tags: settings, bluetooth, nexus-4

My LG Nexus 4 runs stock Android 4.2.2. I use Bluetooth for phone calls with a one-ear headset (Plantronics M100).

Sometimes I notice in the power toggles menu that Bluetooth has turned OFF and when I go into the BT settings the slider is indeed set to OFF. When I touch the slider, it moves to ON but after a fraction of a second it quickly moves back to OFF.

Sometimes Bluetooth is even reported as ON but it still won't connect to any other BT device. In this state, I can turn BT off and then on again, but it doesn't resolve the problem.

Only a **device restart** seems to resolve this, so that I can turn BT on again. This happens every other day or so.

Is this a bug in Android? Is there something else interfering? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I dont know whether this something to with LG, I experience this glitch occasionally in my rooted LG Optimus One (P500), running stock v2.3.3 ROM. I did not face this problem with ROMs from CM7 to CM10.1

Comment: I've experienced this once, I believe after I tried to turn on bluetooth by long-pressing the toggle in the quick settings menu. Do you turn bluetooth on and off a lot? I've found that it isn't much of a battery drain to leave it on without anything connected.

Comment: @Velociraptors: I use a profile app ([Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama)) that turns BT off at night. I'll try leaving it on and see if it helps (and how it affects battery life). Thanks!

Comment: I get this too. FWIW, it's not related to turning Bluetooth on and off a lot - even if I leave it on, it turns itself off and this bug manifests eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to be an Android bug. I found this in the Android bug tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42520&q=summary%3Abluetooth%20type%3Adefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars